# PHP post json result to custom url

Tags: php, json

By default on my web service I must make a post request to custom user's url. I can post the array but I would like to post request as a json payload, the code below could be the post data, but I cannot get the data from PHP.

```
function redirect_to_customer($result = [], $redirect_url = "")
{
    $html = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head></head>
                <body onload="closethisasap();">
                <form name="redirectpost" method="POST" action="' . $redirect_url . '">
        ';
    if (!is_null($result)) {
        $result = json_encode($result);
        $html .= '<input type="hidden" value="' . str_replace('"', "'", $result) . '"> ';
    }
    $html .= "
    </form>
    </body>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        function closethisasap() {
                            document.forms[\"redirectpost\"].submit();
                        }
                    </script>
    </html>";

    echo $html;
}
```

result of this code is :

```
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onload = "closethisasap();">
        <form name = "redirectpost" method = "POST" action = "http://www.sample.com/response.php">
            <input type = "hidden" value = "{'code':'-103','message':'order_id must be unique'}">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function closethisasap()
        {
            document . forms["redirectpost"] . submit();
                }
    </script>
</html>
```

`response.php` user's file content :

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

after post data i get empty array

Comment: `<input type="hidden"` needs a `name`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver OH i'm sorry, thanks. problem solved. please post reply and let me to accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All inputs including `<input type = "hidden"` need a name, so `name = "something"`.